# Python Pygtk making colored tags in Text View dynamically

Tags: python, colors, tags, textview, pygtk

I have seen some ways of making colored text in textview in Python pygtk. the issue seems that it will just print text in that colour or make the whole line that color rather than for certain items make them a certain colour.

I want it to where I type "" that is will colour is blue. or if there is "string" in the text view it will be orange or any kind of

and if there is an '#comment' then it will be italicized and grey.

not sure if it helps, but I have a part where as I am typing it writes the text to a page. is it possible to to keep this kind of syntax coloring active?

I hope this makes sense.

any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you supply some minimal code of how far you've gotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GtkSourceView`](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/) for syntax highlighting. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know of that one.

Comment: First of all , Thank you. I use Linux, is there a decent way of installing cause I it would seem that I have at least 3 dependencies needed to install this.Also is there a way to install and use gtk and webkit in windows. Here will be my source and yes, its a little messy I try to keep it a little organized. I work full time and am at school so sorry I am just getting caught up on it. here is the link: http://pastebin.com/NJ1gjff4

Comment: What is indecent about 3 dependencies?

Comment: I don't know if they're indecencies just I plan to share the program with people at work and when I try to compile the GtkSourceview  I get  that I don't have these dependencies . I was hoping that I could use do this all with out having  to add anything perhaps in the end I will be forced to make a setup.py that will grab them and compile them for the worker. here is the list of dependencies.No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'libxml-2.0' found

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev gives you the gtk 3.0 dependency. for the other sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

Comment: If you compile the program and give it to your co-workers in binary form, they won't need the dependencies. At least not any that end in `-dev`. You shouldn't need to install `libxml2` separately, that's already installed on any Linux system that I know of.

Comment: I got the gtksourceview2 working not 3 but I can settle with this. after all the time of spending to compile the 3.0 (which I see in in the proper spot for some reason python wont import it but oh well.) All I had to do was "sudo apt-get install python-gtksourceview2
". trust me I facepalmed my self.Thank you all for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you are looking for, I'd say, is to use regular expressions (`re` module, there are abundant of questions on this here...probably some for the exact patterns you need) to find the patterns you mention above in your `TextBuffer`. That means you need to connect a signal to the buffer so you see what the user types. Then you'll need a set of `TextTag`s (one tag per formatting rule/pattern) to apply to regions of the buffer where the regular expressions match the patterns you've described. Finally you want to [apply the tags](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--apply-tag) to the buffer and those `TextTag`s can reformat the text-display in the `TextView` in an array of ways ([as the documentation says here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktexttag.html)).

Without any supplied code, it's hard to be precise on where you might be having a problem.

Hope it points you in the right direction...

Mind though that if you overwrite the GTK-theme, that another user could have a theme with e.g. orange background in the `TextView`s, so you should be careful with making sure that it will work visually independent of what theme you have.

Comment: @user1935655 If you plan to not use the `GtkSourceView` that @ptomato wrote about and instead make your own solution as I sketched I would urge you to add some code example to your question as it is really hard to guess exactly what your design is and where your problems are... and in your comment above, what was the question?